# How to call default tool in QGIS inside plugin using python script?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to create a plugin which can draw irregular polygons in QGIS. For that, I want to call the *Select features by freehand* default tool inside my plugin. How can I do this within a  python script?

Comment: You want to call all its functionality (i.e., draw a polygon and select features) or only to draw the polygon?

Comment: I want to draw a irregular polygon select all it's data from table and write it as a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger()
```

Comment: I'm new to qgis so where i want to add this code exactly inside my .py file

Comment: Difficult from me to say. It depends on your plugin's logic. Please see [What is the purpose of some functions and files in QGIS Python plugins?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-the-purpose-of-some-functions-and-files-in-qgis-python-plugins/132604#132604) to figure it out. Most of the cases you would like to put the code in the `run( self )` method. You need to make sure you have stored a reference to the `iface` object inside the `__init__( self, iface )` function.

Comment: Note that you could run the line of code from my answer directly in the QGIS Python console, but in your plugin you would call it this `self.iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger()`.

Comment: @gccarrillo Sorry i dont knw about that.