# QGIS button click run twice

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

*I developed a plugin in QGIS* and I have attached a function on button clicked but it is calling the function two times and I don't know the reason why.

I am registering click function in plugin run event:

```
    def run(self):

        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        AttachBtnClicked(self)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

def AttachBtnClicked(self):
    self.dlg.btnDataSourceEncodingChangeAllLayers.clicked.connect(lambda: btnDataSourceEncodingChangeAllLayersClicked(self))
```

while the method is:

```
   def btnDataSourceEncodingChangeAllLayersClicked(self):
        print 'DataSourceEncodingChanageAllLayers : '# + encodingName
        LayerDataSourceChange()
```

it runs two times.

Comment: Change your signal to `self.dlg.btnDataSourceEncodingChangeAllLayers.clicked.connect(btnDataSourceEncodingChangeAllLayersClicked)` and put it in init method. From run method remove function call.

Comment: @DIVAD if i didnt pass self to function then it will get self

Comment: i think that i am getting this error when my plugin show some error

Comment: button click function run correctly! but some time it run twice or thrice

Comment: by putting in init i am also getting AttributeError: TaskAutomation instance has no attribute 'dlg'

Comment: Put your function AttachBtnClicked inside plugin's class. Then do the same I've said before with a little change in signal: `self.dlg.btnDataSourceEncodingChangeAllLayers.clicked.connec‌​t(self.btnDataSourceEncod‌​ingChangeAllLayersCl‌​icked)`

Comment: what are you talking man? i did not understand

Comment: According to your posted code you have your function AttachBtnClicked out of plugin's class, so I've said to put this function in.

Comment: NameError: global name 'AttachBtnClicked' is not defined

Comment: i added that method into plugin class now calling it at init as you said and getting above error.

Comment: First thing: try to not multiple comments, put all in one. Don't call it in init, just put there signal.

Comment: I have so many signal thats why i make an special method AttachBtnClicked

Comment: So it works or not?

Comment: how can it work when dlg fill in initGui event which runs after init. same dlg error

Comment: We can't post in comments section too many comments. The best and faster way would be if you put your plugin code on pastebin.

Comment: I think you are facing the same problem as [Odd behavior in a QGIS plugin: my function is triggered twice](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137161/4972). You can also read [What is the purpose of some functions and files in QGIS Python plugins?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-the-purpose-of-some-functions-and-files-in-qgis-python-plugins/132604#132604) to get an explanation on what are some plugin functions for.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo what about this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133070/how-to-link-my-qgis-plugin-main-class-to-mouse-events-from-a-custom-tool