# Create Plugin for Qgis 2.10 by using Eclipse

Tags: pyqgis

I finished creating my plugin and then compiled it.

I have : **Myplugin.py, Myplugin_dialog.py, Myplugin_dialog_base.ui**

1. Is it in the **Myplugin_dialog.py** that I'm supposed to create new functions and add *signal/slot* for the components of the dialog?
2. How can I call the components, for exemple a ***QComboBox*** of the **Myplugin_dialog_base.ui** ?

Comment: Perhaps this post might give you _some_ insight: [What is the purpose of some functions and files in QGIS Python plugins?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-the-purpose-of-some-functions-and-files-in-qgis-python-plugins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add your functions in Myplugin.py. You can also add in Myplugin_dialog.py, but for start try add in Myplugin.py
2. Also in Myplugin.py in class Myplugin in function **init** you can catch signals, e.g.
       self.dlg.pushButton.clicked(self.my_function)

Have "def my_function(self):" in the same class.

Comment: It's okey now. Thank you Aerov and thank you Joseph.   I just use the second option that you advice me Aerov. As i'm working on eclipse(Pydev), when i type self.dlg.pushButton; i did not find pusButton appear in the list of components.

Comment: Glad that helped. You can mark it as solved by clicking that tick.
Of course it won't find "pushButton", you must add it in Qt Designer first (open that ...dialog_base.ui in Qt, add pushButton from the menu on left, and it's objectName (seen on right) is that self.dlg."object_name"

Comment: I putted it, but it does not appear in the list when i type. WHen i save it and run it in Qgis, theres no errors.

Comment: So it works? I am not using Eclipse, so I really don't know...