# Icon twice after reloaded plugin

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.14, icon

I am making a QGIS plugin with QGIS 2.14.10

I use the reload plugin each time i want to update the plugin. But sometimes, when my plugin bug and i reload it, i get the icon twice in the toolbar and the first icon is off. It happen each first time that the plugin beug. And sometimes i get 3,4,5 same icon ...

[image]

How can i prevent this ?

Comment: Did you make your plugin from scratch or did you use the **Plugin Builder**? As described in [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-the-purpose-of-some-functions-and-files-in-qgis-python-plugins/132604#132604), you probably need to remove the plugin menu item and icon in the `unload(self)` function. Do you have such code in your plugin and if so, could you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/225253/edit) your question to include this please as this could help potential answerers =)