# QGIS first simple plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to learn how to develop QGIS plugins but I struggle to get going by some simple principles.

As a test I am just trying to connect a function to a button. So when pressed the function run. Where to put the function and connections are not obvious to me.

This example give me an error message `TypeError: test_print() takes no arguments (2 given)` 
I cannot see how this give test_print 2 arguments?

```
def run(self):

    # Run test_print method when pushButton is clicked
    self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test_print)

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

def test_print():
    print 'It works!'
```

Does anyone has any general advice how to wire up buttons and functions properly?

EDIT: Working test example

This worked.

```
def run(self):

        def test_print():
            QMessageBox.about(None,'test','It works!')

        # Run test_print method when pushButton is clicked
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_print)
```

Now, how can i run the test_print method if its not inside def run(self)?

Comment: About your specific issue: you have to add `self` as an argument to `test_print` (i.e. `test_print(self)`).

Comment: It did not work. This works however (see initial question). How can I call a function that is not inside the run method?

Comment: The method provided by @ArMoraer worked for me. Did you receive any errors in the _Python Console_ when you tried using `test_print(self)`?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something very obvious here but I get this `NameError: global name 'test_print' is not defined`

Comment: Is this your entire plugin? Just one file with a "run" function in it?

Comment: @Spacedman No, I used Plugin builder for the structure. So it contain all the default files it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try moving the line:

   ```
   self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test_print)
   ```

   to the `initGui(self)` function instead of in the `run(self)` function.

---

2. As [@ArMoraer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64955/armoraer) mentioned, put your `test_print(self)` outside the `run(self)` function.

---

3. Here is the part of the *Example.py* script I used to test it:

   ```
   def initGui(self):
       """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
       icon_path = ':/plugins/Example/icon.png'
       self.add_action(
           icon_path,
           text=self.tr(u'Example'),
           callback=self.run,
           parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

       # Run test_print method when pushButton is clicked
       self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test_print)

   def run(self):        
       """Run method that performs all the real work"""
       # show the dialog
       self.dlg.show()
       result = self.dlg.exec_()
       if result:
           pass

   def test_print(self):
       print 'It works!'
   ```

---

You can also take a look at the following post which describes the fundamental parts of a QGIS plugin:

[What is the purpose of some functions and files in QGIS Python plugins?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131535/what-is-the-purpose-of-some-functions-and-files-in-qgis-python-plugins)

Comment: Great now it works! Really appreciate it, a good simple starting point.
I created a new plugin from the Plugin builder and both @Joseph and @ArMoraer works. I just found that i had moved `self.dlg = TestPluginDialog()` from the `add_action` method to the init (followed an example before) that made it not functioning properly. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @geogrow - Most welcome and nice one! Glad you got it working =)